# paraId to chain name mappings?

Tags: xcmp

I would like to associate paraIds with particular parachains as is done in [polkadot-js parachains tab](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpolkadot.api.onfinality.io%2Fpublic-ws#/parachains). I notice that they [hardcode all the paraIds](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/7325/files). I can get a list of parachain ids from the relay chain but all I can find is linkage to accounts ( `slots / leases` ). I can see that if I query each individual parachain and ask it for `parachaininfo / parachainId()` they will tell me their paraIds but I am wondering if there's a slicker solution? Or is the decentralised nature such that querying the parachains individually is the best option?

(I tag this as xcmp as when you see an xcmp message going to 2012 you need to understand which chain is paraId 2012 for it to make sense.)

Answer (score 1):

parachaininfo / parachainId() is the only way at the moment. It works well enough.